# How to Change The WordPress Login URL Without Plugin

Tags: wp-admin, login, htaccess, security

I'm looking for a way to change the wordpress admin login url from site.com/wp-login.php or sit.com/wp-admin.php to my custom login url like site.com/mylogin.
I want to this without using plugin or changing wordpress core files.
I have already tried method 2 of [this page](https://www.mediumtalk.net/change-wordpress-login-url-without-plugin/) .
everything is ok but it has a problem with woocommerce my-account page. users can not logout from this page.
please help me to fix this problem.
P.S: what do you think about [this solution](https://w3reign.com/how-to-change-wp-admin-url-in-wordpress-without-plugin/)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use a plugin for that? [WPS Hide Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) does exactly that and from version 1.9.1 they no longer have a vulnerability that exposes the login page url. You could copy pase the plugin code into your theme directly, some changes would need to be applied because the paths would be different.

Comment: I prefer to see exactly what is going on and I think adding just a few lines of code is much better than using a plugin with extra and useless classes. another reason is that once our website hacked becuase of a plugin so I don't have a good feeling about them :(

Comment: Understandable. The WPS Hide Login plugin does a good job for that, as I said, I you don't want to use it, go into the [source code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wps-hide-login/trunk) and see how it was made, you could pick out the code that you want and omit the rest, i'm pretty sure this plugin is barebone so most likely its all relevant. Looking in the source code of plugins is what I usualy do when I don't want to use a bloated plugin.

Comment: there's a difference between moving/hiding the WP login, and using a custom login/logout page. It sounds like you actually want a custom login/logout page, not to move the login page. _You can have both a custom login page and the standard login page and redirect to the custom one when users access the original_. Plugins such as WPS Hide Login etc may not be what you want. Also I would strongly advise against following the tutorial you linked to, it is giving you bad advice. Any tutorial that tells you to create new top level PHP files for logins should not be trusted

Comment: @Tom J Nowell Thank you. I want to hide it and change to a url that only admin know. thank you for your advise. most sites just tell to change core files. I think it is a bad idea too.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thank you. I will check the code.

Comment: @Nina _that does not improve security it may even harm it_, security through obscurity is just theatre, it does not make your site more secure. For example did you know that there's a permalink `/login` that redirects to the location of the login page? If you moved it properly then that link would redirect users to the new place anyway. The same with `/admin` and `/wp-admin`. Stopping that would mean breaking any code that relies on the login URL (which includes some plugins that use it for other purposes). You'll also break passworded posts and account resets

Comment: Changing the WP login URL is a common security suggestion from listicles that has no basis in fact. Instead, install a 2FA plugin and a means to block repeated failed logins. Hiding that you're using WordPress, hiding WP-Admin, hiding the login URL, these do not improve security. Notice that the largest biggest WordPress websites that are the biggest targets do not hide these things or move them around